# Outlook on-send Add-In popup a dialog in OWA but not in Desktop

Tags: outlook, office-js, office-addins, outlook-web-addins, action-send

Our Add-In is using the On-Send functionality and it used to work for both OWB and Desktop without any problems.

Now I have 2 issues that prevent my users using the add-in:

1. On Desktop, when sending an email or a meeting, there is a message saying "...is working on your request" which never disappears and nothing happen. that prevent users from sending emails and meetings.
2. On OWA, when sending an email or a meeting, an alert popups

   > Do you trust the domain undefined where this Office session is hosted? This Office session is not using a secure connection. We recommend that you take extra precautions."

   Why is the domain *undefined*? where I should define it?
   It creates a-lot of confusion for the users, is it possible for an admin to set it up for all users?

'Do you trust the domain' alert

[image]

Comment: Could you please provide the Exchange version and Outlook build numbers? Also, is this for an on Prem account?

Comment: I tested it on my Outlook (personal) live account, and under my (work) office365 account.
Both gave me the same results.
I am using Outlook for Mac version 16.49 (21050901). license: Microsoft 365 Subscription

Comment: Follow up on github post for further updates- https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js/issues/1874

Comment: @OutlookAdd-insTeam-MSFT any updates? 
a lot of users encounter that issue and it's preventing them from using Outlook Desktop without uninstalling the add-in.